# Using a step by step relay along with a solid state relay

Tags: mains, solid-state-relay

I have a step by step relay which is connected to a light bulb and to a manual switch.
In parallel with the manual switch I put a SSR. I command the SSR to be on for 0.5 seconds, however the light would not switch(although the manual switch works).

Is there a problem because the SSR is a zero crossing relay? Or should I look somewhere else? How could I make this assembly to work?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foK6OU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid. Add the datasheet for the SSR.

Comment: "*Is there a problem because the SSR is a zero crossing relay?*" We don't even know what voltage your circuit is or whether it's DC or AC. We don't know how you are driving the SSR. There is way too much information missing from your question.

Comment: I added the schematic, also the step by step relay model and the SSR model. The SSR model is controlled by an ESP8266

Comment: The datasheet link for the SSR didn't come through.

Comment: https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/g3mb-ssr-datasheet.pdf sorry

Comment: You're not making this easy. There are six SSRs listed on that datasheet, three of which are zero-cross. How do you know if the SSR module is receiving a signal? Are there LEDs on it? If so, do they light. Please take a step back, edit your question and put **all** the required information into it. Check it before submitting.

Comment: Yes there are leds and I'm sure it's a zero cross SSR (I tried to use it in the past to control 12V DC and had an issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/finder/27-01-8-230-0000/relay-spst-no-110vac-10a/dp/1455194) your relay has a coil resistance of 6.5 kΩ. That means that the maximum current it will draw is about 33 mA on 230 V AC.

[image]

*Figure 1. The SSR output rating shows that it has a minimum load current of 0.10 A.*

Since 33 mA < 0.10 A the SSR can not turn on reliably so the relay does not energise.

For further reading on SSRs and how the zero-cross detection works see what I've written [here](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).

Comment: Would it be sufficient to put a resistor in parallel with the step by step relay such that it allows about 100 mA?

Comment: You could but power rating of the resistor will be \$ P = VI = 220 * 0.1 = 22 \ \text W \$ so it will waste power and get very hot. (You'd probably choose a 50 W resistor so it would run cooler.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a Zero Crossing Switch (ZCS Triac) SSR but not a latching relay. But you can provide positive feedback to the SSR output to make it a latching or Step Relay for SET. Then you need another switch for RESET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwhSgr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I took the liberty of fixing your design. You must figure out how it works.

Comment: darn editor with hidden lines